# Storing matrices in an array in visual basic 6

Tags: arrays, matrix, vb6

I am new to vb6 programming and i have the following problem.

I am computing some 2x2 matrices inside a for loop and i want to store these matrices in an array. To be more precise i want to know if there is something like the cell array in Matlab. That is (for a 1x2 cell array and 2x2 matrices) i can have

```
cell_example{1} = A1
cell_example{2} = A2
```

where each of A1, A2 are 2x2 matrices. Is there anything like this in vb6?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I realise you have the answer now, but a useful term to look for regarding this sort of thing is jagged arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim m As Variant
ReDim m(1 To 2)

Dim ar1() As Long, ar2() As Long
ReDim ar1(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
ReDim ar2(1 To 2, 1 To 2)

m(1) = ar1
m(2) = ar2

'Accessing
m(1)(1,2) = 42
```

Note that this copies `ar1` and `ar2` into `m`, not puts them by reference.